# Require file in google cloud storage from google cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google

Is it possible to `require` directly file in storage from google cloud function with the same project_id? without creating the HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

Cloud functions can respond directly to change notifications coming from Google Cloud Storage. You can check all the relevant documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) and an HTTP trigger is not needed.

If what is required is to do some operations with a file (object) stored in Google Cloud Storage using Cloud Functions please refer to the [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) section. Find an example [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/index.html#example-usage) using the Python Client for Google Cloud Storage.